# How to install latest awscli using yum on CentOS 7?

Tags: amazon-web-services, centos7, yum

I installed on CentOS 7 awscli using this command:

```
yum install awscli
```

But it turned out that it is old version of awscli:

```
awscli.noarch             1.14.28-5.el7_5.1
```

How could I update or install using yum on CentOS 7 to get awscli 1.18?

Comment: have you tried this one https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-linux.html

Comment: yes @MiguelTrejo I checked it but we need yum install awscli and there is not explained that part.

Answer (score 4):

AWS documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-linux.html) clearly mentions as below. Looks like it is not recommended to use the yum appraoch.

> Although the awscli package is available in repositories for other package managers such as apt and yum, these are not produced, managed, or supported by AWS. We recommend that you install the AWS CLI from only the official AWS distribution points, as documented in this guide.

Comment: Thank you @Praveen Sripati I missed that. I only checked that there is no command for that and google all around. you helped me a lot :)